# I can use two connections with different database using prisma?

Tags: node.js, prisma

I'm trying to use different databases with the prisma, one database would be for read-only and the other for write, I need to configure it in my project and use it inside the UseCase, how to do that?

I tried to configure two schemas but I couldn't call them inside the UseCase

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can create two PrismaClientInstances, one with read access and one with write access

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const client1 = new PrismaClient({ datasources: { db: { url: 'postgres://localhost/db1' }} })
const client2 = new PrismaClient({ datasources: { db: { url: 'postgres://localhost/db2' }} })
```

You are essentially overriding the database url while instantiating a prisma client.

Here client1 could be read-only and client2 can be with write access.

You can read more about it here: [#2443](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2443)